# Is there a way to retrieve the HTML content of a web page by casting it into a string in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to retrieve the HTML content of a web page and extract it  and read it as a string. However, I have a problem, whenever I run my code I get a bytes like object instead of a string and **decode()** does not seem to work in this case.

My code is the following:

```
money_request = urllib.request.urlopen('website-url-here').read()

print(money_request.decode('utf-8')
```

Running the above script will yield the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\University Stuff\Licenta\gas_station_service.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(money_request.decode())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02bb' in position 143288: character maps to <undefined>
>>>
```

I would also like to specify that I have checked if the website uses utf-8 encoding using the Chrome console and the command **document.characterSet**.

I need to retrieve this as a string in order to perform a search on the lines of code to get a value from a span tag.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Based on the error, `money_request.decode('utf-8')` is working fine; it's the attempt (via the call to `print`) to *encode* the resulting `str` for display on your terminal that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be would be better if you use the beautiful soup because it help to parse into html
if you don't have this module install it like `pip install bs4` on windows and `pip3 install bs4` if on mac or linux and i hope requests already exists in python 3 and if you don't have lxml module go ahead and install it with pip install

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = request.get('website-url-here')
src = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
markup = soup.prettify()
print(markup)
```

and you'll get the entire page of the scraping web may be would would be easy for you
to extract the useful on
by finding the contents that you want

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class', 'classname'})
```

this will return into array while this don't

```
soup.find('div', {'class', 'classname'})
```

but this will return the first content the choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `text` to get a string of the website html code

```
import requests
response = requests.get('website-url-here')
print(response.text)
```